# Assigning Value to an @Input binding

Tags: angular

I have been fairly used to changing the values of my `@Inputs` in my components for some time now until recently, during a pull request review, a colleague of mine commented:

> assigning an @Input? (╬ Ò ‸ Ó)

So now I am curious. Is this necessarily a bad thing to do? If I want to change an `@Input()` binding, should I instead create a `set` accessor for it?

**Previous:**

```
@Input() name: string;

public changeName(): void {
    this.name = 'Bob';
}
```

**Current:**

```
private nameInternal: string;

@Input set name(value: string) {
    this.nameInternal = value;
}
```

Is there a preferred way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: If you set it, it is not an input anymore.
Why do you have to set it ? Maybe you could emit an event so that the parent can change it himself. Because if you change it in your component, it won't change in the parent component.

Comment: What do you expect when you change `name` in code? Do you want the bound value to change also?

Comment: in general, you should not alter the `input` value within child component, as the change might not be propagated back to parent component. This could lead to confusing bugs...If you do want this behavior, ngModel might be better options.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you want to set the input, if you want to keep a pure uni-directional dataflow you can use the EventEmitter API and @Output decorator to notify parent components that something has changed and do the modification in the parent component.

First, you need import **Output** and **eventEmitter** to decorate a new change property inside your component.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ … })
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() 
  name: string;
  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  // …

  }
```

Our change output is of type EventEmitter and  we are emitting a string type

To invoke the event EventEmitter instance  we call our this.change() method to emit an event to the parent.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1> <button type="button" (click)="changeName()"> Change name</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() 
  name: string;
  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  changeName(){
    this.change.emit('Bob');
  }
}
```

This will then emit a change to our (change) listener we setup in the parent

```
<hello 
name="{{ name }}"
(change)="nameChange($event)">
</hello>
```

Next link shows a working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjbczx